# Ensure the order of Div Components in a Dash App

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When I create a dash app that includes a sidebar in which users can select part of the data which is then plotted (and listed in another tab), I run into the issue that the different `dcc` components do not remain in the order that I specified.

**UPDATE**

I created a simplified reproducible example. I have no experience with html and CSS, so I wanted to ask you how to make sure that the `html.Div` and `html.P` nicely follow the order as specified in the below code:

So: Gender--Join Date-Birthdate-State

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Customer': [111, 222, 555, 666],
        'zip_city': ['Aguadilla', 'Aguadilla', 'Arecibo', 'Wrangell'],
        'zip_state': ['PR', 'TX', 'CA', 'MI'],
        'zip_latitude':[18.498987, 18.498987, 18.449732,56.409507],
        'zip_longitude':[-67.13699,-67.13699,-66.69879,-132.33822],
        'Birtdate': pd.to_datetime(['1964-04-28','1994-04-18','1993-04-04','1997-05-03'], format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True, dayfirst=True),
        'JoinDate': pd.to_datetime(['1980-08-02','2008-03-24','2004-12-17','2010-12-11'], format="%Y-%m-%d", utc=True, dayfirst=True),
        'Gender':['m','f','m','alien']})



df["CustomerCount"] = df.groupby(["zip_city"], as_index=False)["Customer"].transform("count")

gender_options = []
for gender in df['Gender'].unique():
    gender_options.append({'label':str(gender),
                           'value':gender})

state_options = []
for state in df['zip_state'].unique():
    gender_options.append({'label':str(state),
                           'value':state})

app = dash.Dash()


app.css.append_css({'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'})

app.layout = html.Div([html.H1('A Dashboard', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
                       html.Div(children=[
                            html.H1('Input', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
                            html.H6('Gender'),
                            html.P(
                                    dcc.Checklist(id='gender-picker',
                                    options=gender_options,
                                    values=['m','f']
                                    )
                                ),
                            html.H6('Join Date'),
                            html.P(
                                    dcc.DatePickerRange(
                                            id='joindate',
                                            min_date_allowed=min(df.JoinDate),
                                            max_date_allowed=max(df.JoinDate),
                                            initial_visible_month=dt(1989, 11, 9),
                                            start_date=min(df.JoinDate),
                                            end_date=max(df.JoinDate)
                                            )
                                    ),
                            html.H6('Birthdate'),
                            html.P(
                                    dcc.DatePickerRange(
                                            id='birthdate',
                                            min_date_allowed=min(df['Birtdate']),
                                            max_date_allowed=max(df['Birtdate']),
                                            initial_visible_month=dt(1989, 11, 9),
                                            start_date=min(df['Birtdate']),
                                            end_date=max(df['Birtdate'])
                                            )
                                    ),
                            html.H6('State'),
                            html.P(html.Div([
                            dcc.Checklist(id='state-picker',
                                          options=state_options,
                                          values= df['zip_state'].unique().tolist()
                                          )
                                        ])
                                        )
                                ],
                               style = {'float':'left'},
                                className = "two columns"
                            ),
                        html.Div([dcc.Tabs(children=[dcc.Tab(label='Map',
                                                            children=html.Div([
                                                                    dcc.Graph(id='CustomerMap')
                                                                    ])
                                                            ),
                                                    dcc.Tab(label='Data',
                                                            children=[html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
                                                                                id='table',
                                                                                columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                                                                                data = df.to_dict("rows")
                                                                                )])
                                                                    ]
                                                            )
                                                    ]
                                            )
                                ])
                        ]
                    )

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('CustomerMap', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('gender-picker', 'values')])

def update_figure(selected_gender):    
    filtered_df = df[df['Gender'].isin(selected_gender)]
    filtered_df["CustomerCount"] = filtered_df.groupby(["zip_city"], as_index=False)["Customer"].transform("count")

    customerCount = filtered_df['CustomerCount'].tolist()
    zipcity = filtered_df['zip_city'].tolist()
    hovertext = []
    for i in range(len(customerCount)):
        k = str(zipcity[i]) + ':' + str(customerCount[i])
        hovertext.append(k)
    return {'data':[dict(
                        type = 'scattergeo',
                        locationmode = 'USA-states',
                        lon = filtered_df['zip_longitude'],
                        lat = filtered_df['zip_latitude'],
                        text = hovertext,
                        hoverinfo = 'text',
                        marker = dict(
                        size = filtered_df['CustomerCount'],
                        line = dict(width=0.5, color='rgb(40,40,40)'),
                        sizemode = 'area'
                        ),
                        transforms = [dict(
                        type = 'aggregate',
                        groups = filtered_df['zip_city'],
                        aggregations = [dict(target = filtered_df['Customer'], func = 'count', enabled = True)]
                                        )
                                        ]
                        )
                    ]
            }


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('table', 'data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('gender-picker', 'values')])

def update_table(selected_gender):    
    filtered_df = df[df['Gender'].isin(selected_gender)]
    filtered_df["CustomerCount"] = filtered_df.groupby(["zip_city"], as_index=False)["Customer"].transform("count")
    return filtered_df.to_dict("rows")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

But in the app it stacks the options of the two checkboxes:
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, I think it works, isn't this what you want? [image]

Comment: Yes as I said the problem is that in the app I have many more input options that stack on each other and then it looks like in the screenshot attached. I am extremely puzzled why this is. My question is how to ensure the `dcc` components remain in their order?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it was a copy-paste error:

```
gender_options = []
for gender in df['Gender'].unique():
    gender_options.append({'label':str(gender),
                           'value':gender})

state_options = []
for state in df['zip_state'].unique():
    gender_options.append({'label':str(state),
                           'value':state})
```

Obviously the second loop will add the states to the gender, which means I exactly get the output I requested, but not the one I wanted! Changing the second part into:

```
state_options = []
for state in df['zip_state'].unique():
    state_options.append({'label':str(state),
                           'value':state})
```

Solved the problem.